# How to compile CLucene for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cmake, clucene

I am trying to compile CLucene for iOS and running into some problems.

Here are the steps I've taken

1. Modify the CLucene CMakeLists.txt to disable multithreading
2. Create a "build-ios" directory in the CLucene source directory
3. Drop the cmake file from this site into the cmake directory http://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/
4. run the following command "cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./iOS.cmake -GXcode ../"

Here's the output from that command. Can someone help me out with the error?

-- Toolchain using default iOS SDK: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - not found.
-- Could NOT find Boost
Boost not found, using local: /Users/aschuler/Desktop/clucene-core-2.3.3.4/src/ext
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-6.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Threads (missing: Threads_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake 2.8-6.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Applications/CMake 2.8-6.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:157 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/shared/CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

looks like boost is missing. boost is a required library - check the readme

Comment: What I don't really understand is boost is located at the path it's calling out. Another things is that if I just run the regular Xcode script it throws the boost not found error but still builds the whole project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been long. But just try Cmake with Zlib. Because i am in the process of doing the same thing you did, but waiting till i receive the MAc mini. If you have found the solution please do share because it will be helpful for me and many others. Thank you.